# D3 Scroll a node into view

Tags: d3.js

I'm using a D3 tree. Similar to: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063570 
However, this particular diagram is bigger than the browser window.

Given that i know exactly which one of the JSON element's that i want to reveal.

How could i scroll that element into view within the svg canvas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is probably to wrap what you want to appear in a `g` element and use a transition on the translation.

```
groupToShow.attr("transform", "translate(1000,1000)")
   .transition()
   .duration(1000)
   .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");
```

Adapt the values for translation and duration as needed.